# conjunction to link two clauses

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

I am wondering whether the conjunction **though** makes sense in the following.

> It is regarded as a symbol of respect and prestige to have a handcrafted coffin in this country **though** only the heads of households who have achieved some level of success may have one.

The context is a discussion of handcrafted coffins in a country.

Comment: What objection might be made against "though"? It is used to introduce a qualification to a thought.

Comment: What relation holds between the two clauses if "though" is used?

Comment: Consider: *It is a symbol of prestige to own a high-end Mercedes though few, if any, manual laborers own one.*    That is a misuse of **though** on a semantic level.  The clause introduced by **though** introduces a contrary idea which, at first glance, does not flow from the initial clause.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You are saying the original sentence doesn't make sense, because "because" should be used instead, aren't you?

Comment: **because** works, sort of; with **because**, the sentence defines a prestige item as one that only a few successful heads of households would have, rather than one which only a few would be able to afford.

Comment: The semantic problem with the predicate in the first clause of your sentence is that it conflates or combines two very different ideas, respect and prestige.   Thus, the **though**  clause must counter two very different ideas.

Comment: Are you saying the sentence in the OP has two problems, first with though not used to introduce a contrary idea, and the other with the though-clause only addressing prestige?

Comment: What about "It is regarded as a symbol of prestige to have a handcrafted coffin in this country though only the heads of households who have achieved some level of success may have one"? Does it sound natural now, with "though" and "a symbol of prestige" instead of "a symbol of respect and prestige"?

Comment: It sounded natural enough to begin with, but not all that sounds natural makes perfect sense. Now it makes better sense.  It would make even better sense if you said "who **had** achieved"  unless it is common in this country to buy the coffin while one is still living.

Comment: There is still the problem of the tautological relationship of the two clauses connected by **though**.  *The Mercedes is a very expensive car though few people will own them.*  TAUTOLOGY.

Comment: A handcrafted coffin is a symbol of respect though only the wealthy can afford one. GOOD.   A handcrafted coffin is a symbol of prestige though only the wealthy can afford one. TAUTOLOGICAL.

Comment: It's fine. The preposition "though" introduces a concessive adjunct, a clause that typically expresses contrast.

Comment: I have to say that a great deal of cultural knowledge is being assumed in this discussion that the English language itself does not assume. Is it true in the culture being described that only the wealthy have respect or prestige? No one is esteemed for good works or knowledge? Does the culture being described equate success solely with self-earned wealth? Does the "may" in the original mean that some are prohibited from being buried in such coffins, or does it indicate choice? It is why I started with asking what were the OP's objections: the original sentence is rife with cultural ambiguity.

Comment: @BillJ: Where's the contrast?

Comment: The possible contrast in the original sentence is that a hand crafted coffin in that culture is a mark of respect and prestige although not all who have respect and prestige have such a coffin, either because it is prohibited or it is not elected. The problem is not "though." For example, "A hand-crafted coffin is a mark of respect and prestige though only the wealthy can afford one" is a perfectly good sentence. The subordinate clause introduced by "though" must make a qualifying statement, not a contrary statement, which necessarily would be nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When two clauses are joined by **though** the second clause must counter the idea expressed in the first clause with a predicate that would not normally flow from that of the first clause.

> The place has nothing but rain in the summer and the streets are
>   dangerous at night though tourists flock there for some reason. <sup>good</sup>
>
> The Z-Class LuxusMobile is a very expensive car though few can afford it. <sup>tautological (no contrast)</sup>
>
> The Z-Class LuxusMobile is a prestige vehicle though few can afford it. <sup>tautological (no contrast)</sup>
>
> The Z-Class LuxusMobile is very reliable because it uses only the finest parts and components available which are rarely, if ever, used in average cars, though few can afford it. <sup>perfectly grammatical but semantically marginal because the simple contrast of "reliability" and "affordability" is muddied by the other statements about high cost</sup>

We cannot fix the LuxusMobile example by saying **because** instead of **though**.

> The Z-Class LuxusMobile is a very expensive car because few can afford it.

There, cause and effect are backwards.

> The Z-Class LuxusMobile is a luxury car that many desire but few can afford.
>
> The Z-Class LuxusMobile is a luxury car that many desire though few can afford.

P.S. OP has submitted another sentence in the comments below, which I include here:

> "It is regarded as a great honor and a sign of respect to have a
>   handcrafted coffin in this country though only the heads of households
>   who have achieved some level of success may be buried in one."

and has clarified that "having" a coffin is the same as owning one and being buried in it; and "may" means "are permitted".

The sentence then has this basic structure:

"Fancy coffins are considered an honor though the honor is one few people are permitted to receive".

The second clause introduced by **though** is thus a kind of qualification.

**People consider the fancy coffin an honor for the deceased and a sign of (their?) respect (for the deceased) but they are not permitted to bestow that honor on and show that respect to just anyone.**

That qualification has nothing to do with the general opinion of the fancy coffin and its symbolism per se. Rather, it is a restriction placed on those who wish to use the symbol.  The clause introduced by **though** is thus more a supplement or an adjunct than it is integral.

> People regard a handcrafted coffin as a way to honor and show respect
>   to the dead—though only a head of household who had reached a
>   certain level of success is permitted to be buried in such a coffin.

Comment: Do you think the sentence, which is slightly different from my OP sentence, is natural? "It is regarded as a great honor and a sign of respect to have a handcrafted coffin in this country though only the heads of households who have achieved some level of success may be buried in one."

Comment: Or is it tautological?

Comment: Does "having" a coffin mean the same thing as being "buried" in a coffin? Or is there a hand-crafted coffin rental business, where the hand-crafted coffin is just for show, temporarily?

Comment: Please assume there's no difference between being buried in a coffin and owning one. Also, it's not a rental business.

Comment: OK, just making sure of the nature of the contrast.

Comment: What does **may be buried in one** mean?  "are likely to be buried in one" or  "are permitted to be buried in one"?

Comment: For the present purposes, it means "be permitted to be buried in one."

Comment: Please see the P.S. which will appear momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

To compare or to contrast, commonality or distinction -- our choice of preposition depends on which relationship we wish to establish.

We use "as" to compare, to establish a relationship based on commonality.

> It is regarded as a symbol of respect and prestige to have a handcrafted coffin in this country, as only the heads of households who have achieved some level of success may have one.

In this version of the sentence, there is a commonality between "respect and prestige" and "some level of success".   It would be reasonable to assume that *respect and prestige* are the natural result of being a successful head of a household.   It would also be reasonable to assume that people who don't head a household won't get a handcrafted coffin, even when they otherwise have enough respect and prestige to deserve one.

We use "though" to contrast, to establish a relationship based on distinction.

> It is regarded as a symbol of respect and prestige to have a handcrafted coffin in this country, though only the heads of households who have achieved some level of success may have one.

Here, the most likely contrast is between symbolic and literal representations.   On the one hand, the coffin symbolizes respect and prestige.   On the other, the coffin literally represents household success, probably through household wealth.

The contrast of "though" establishes that the *respect and prestige* so symbolized has little to do with success as a head of a household.   It's reasonable to assume that there are successful heads of households who get handcrafted coffins despite having never having earned the symbolized respect and prestige.   It's still reasonable to assume that people who don't head a household won't get a handcrafted coffin, regardless.

Both versions are grammatically correct and semantically sound.   The relationship between these two referents has both elements of commonality and elements of distinction.   In this context, an author must choose whether the commonality or the distinction is more relevant.   That choice leads directly to the choice of preposition.

"Though" makes sense.   "As" would also make sense, though it would make a different sense, establishing a different relationship and different meanings for the related items.

Comment: Do you think "whereas" works?

Comment: "Whereas" has two common uses.  In one, it does mark a contrast.  In the other, it merely marks circumstances, usually contributory circumstances.  "Whereas" would imply that success as a head of a household contributes to the respect and prestige that the coffin symbolizes.  Again, choosing a different preposition establishes a different relationship.  Taken out of context, this relationship is also sensible.  Without seeing the full context, I have no way of knowing whether this sensible relationship is appropriate.